# Firestore rules, atomic writes, and write limits

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a two-part question regarding Firestore rule evaluations. The parts are related which is why the single question here...

**Part I - Atomic write access**

Let's say that I have a written rule such as

```
allow write: if resource.data.claimedBy == null && request.data.claimedBy == request.auth.uid;
```

The idea is that any user can make a claim to this resource. But, what if this resource is made available to 1000 users all at once and they all jump to make a claim and make the `.update()` call all at the same time?

Will this be a first wins scenario? Firebase will be set as the field for the first user, the winner, and then everyone else will have their writes rejected because the rule would fail due to a value being present from the winner's write? Or is there any risk whatsoever that a race condition could result and somehow for a moment the value was one thing and then became another?

I feel like the rules would prohibit a race condition, but I don't know for certain.

**Part II - Write limits**

Ok, so this part builds off of the first. Firestore has a write limit of 1 write/second in general for a single document. Let's assume Part I works how I hope and the other 999 users will get a write rejection. Do these rejections count towards the write limit of 1 write/sec because a write was initiated, or do they not count because the rules prohibit an actual write?

Obviously, having all these claim attempts at once count as 1000 writes would be bad for the 1 write/second limit.

I am assuming here, but I believe it would not count toward that limit because my understanding is that the limit is imposed by the nature of the underlying storage mechanics, and the rules prevent going to that layer upon rejection. But also again, I don't know for certain.

**Part III - Bonus part**

Do writes that are rejected by a rule still count as a "write" as far as billing is concerned? I know a query for a document that does not exist (no documents actually read) still counts as a single read, so I am wondering if writes with regards to rules which prohibit the underlying write works in a similar way and incurs a charge.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try/figure out whether your rule schema guarantees atomic writes?

Comment: @imikim I was told elsewhere from a google employee on the firebase team that no client will ever be informed that their write completed properly and then learn afterward that it did not. Basically, they confirmed that rules forced atomicity in the way I was asking :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to avoid and prevent concurrent writes.  The transaction can check if the document was previously claimed, then abort if it was.

If a write was denied by a rule, it doesn't count toward any write limits or billing, as no data in the document was actually changed.

Comment: Thank you! How certain are you on your second statement? As for your first statement, I do agree about the use of transactions for the client code that I write myself, but when considering that calls can be made outside of my own client code where transactions may not be used, I am wanting certainty that transactions are essentially "useless"/unnecessary in a situation where there is a rule such as given in my example.

Comment: You will have to ensure that all clients use a transaction.  If you don't do this, you can't ensure that writes are atomic, and one write could clobber another.  I am certain about the second part.

Comment: Thank you again. To me, transactions are good for concurrent writes where all writes should/could be considered. If I didn't have that rule, I 100% agree that non-transaction writes would clobber each other. However, I am trying to determine if a rule like I've written will in fact prevent all subsequent/concurrent writes and do so in an atomic way. The mechanics of how/when rules are evaluated is the critical piece.

Comment: If you are correct that I would have to ensure transactions, when accounting for malicious clients, I think my only option is to have "claims" be made via a firebase function which uses a transaction and restrict direct write access to the clients. This wouldn't be so terrible, but it would force one more read per claim for the transaction logic and would impose a slightly longer delay invoking functions.

Comment: Sure, if you want to make everyone go through an endpoint. that's valid.